# Ensure that UserControl is completely done painting itself before running a method

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I have a mainwindow form that acts like a mdi form. When a user selects an option from a menu, the mainwindow will load a UserControl to display.

```
Private Sub treNavTree_NodeMouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) Handles treNavTree.NodeMouseClick

Dim nextDisplay As UserControl = GetUserControl(e.Node.Text)
If nextDisplay Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

pnlMain.Controls.Remove(currentDisplay)
currentDisplay = nextDisplay

pnlMain.Controls.Add(currentDisplay, 1, 0)
currentDisplay.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

currentDisplay.Show()

End Sub
```

Each of these UserControls that are loaded have a ListView with many items that are fetched from the database. As it stands, these listviews are populated with said items on the UserControl.Load event. This is a problem because the UserControl.Paint visibly flickers/hangs while waiting for these large listviews to populate. My idea was to move the loading of the listview outside of the UserControl's Load event into its own method, and call that after the call to Show(). Unfortunately, it seems as though the UserControl does not finish Show completely first before beginning to load the listview. At least, it still hangs in exactly the same way. Why is this so? is it not finishing completely before starting the next line? I suspect so, because of the difference between Show() and ShowDialog(). MSDN says that code continues to be executed after a call to Show() as opposed to ShowDialog(). How can I ensure that my UserControl is completely done painting itself before running my LoadListView method? I have tried every suggestion on the internet in order to minimize flickering. Nothing works. I need this to happen. Thanks!

```
Private Sub treNavTree_NodeMouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) Handles treNavTree.NodeMouseClick

Dim nextDisplay As UserControl = GetUserControl(e.Node.Text)
If nextDisplay Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

pnlMain.Controls.Remove(currentDisplay)
currentDisplay = nextDisplay

pnlMain.Controls.Add(currentDisplay, 1, 0)
currentDisplay.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

currentDisplay.Show()
currentDisplay.LoadListView()  'Load the listview after done showing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying several different methods I was unable to find a way to `.Show()` the next UserControl without immediately initiating the loading of the ListView. I am now pretty sure it must run .Show() asynchronously and continue processing the next lines while loading the form, making it unavoidable. So, I made my own background worker and did the loading of the listview on that thread, while loading the UserControl on the main thread, joining the background worker thread back to the main thread after the loading is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Suspend/ResumeLayout() may do the trick:

```
Private Sub treNavTree_NodeMouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) Handles treNavTree.NodeMouseClick

    Dim nextDisplay As UserControl = GetUserControl(e.Node.Text)
    If nextDisplay Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Me.SuspendLayout()   
    pnlMain.Controls.Remove(currentDisplay)
    currentDisplay = nextDisplay

    currentDisplay.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    pnlMain.Controls.Add(currentDisplay, 1, 0)
    Me.ResumeLayout()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion